# linq to xml how to move one element from one xml to another

Tags: linq-to-xml

i am facing one problem
i have two xml files.

**Plugins.xml**

```
<SolutionProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile">
      <Modules>
        <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="PluginXXX.dll" />
      </Modules>
    </SolutionProfile>
```

**ProfileCatalog.xml**

```
<SolutionProfile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile/2.0">
  <Section Name="Services">
    <Modules>
      <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="Module.dll" />
    </Modules>
  </Section>
  <Section Name="Apps">
    <Dependencies>
      <Dependency Name="Services" />
    </Dependencies>
    <Modules>
      <ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="PluginABC.dll" >
    </Modules>
  </Section>
</SolutionProfile>
```

i wants to move PluginXXX.dll from Plugins.xml to ProfileCatalog.xml.

the code i used is as

```
public static void PluginLoaded(string pluginName)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
            settings.Indent = true;

            XDocument pluginDoc = XDocument.Load("Plugins.xml");
            XDocument profileCatalogDoc = XDocument.Load("ProfileCatalog.xml");

            XmlWriter pluginDocXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("Plugins.xml", settings);
            XmlWriter profileCatalogDocXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create("ProfileCatalog.xml", settings);


            XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile";

            var res = from plugin in pluginDoc.Descendants(ns + "ModuleInfo")
                      where plugin.Attribute("AssemblyFile").Value == pluginName
                      select plugin;

            // save the plugin to remove
            XElement pluginToMove = res.FirstOrDefault();

            //remove from xml
            res.FirstOrDefault().Remove();

            // save xml back
            pluginDoc.Save(pluginDocXmlWriter);



            XNamespace pns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile/2.0";

            var pRes = ((from pcPlugin in profileCatalogDoc.Descendants(pns + "Modules")
                         select pcPlugin).Skip(1).Take(1)).FirstOrDefault();

            pRes.Add(pluginToMove);

            profileCatalogDoc.Save(profileCatalogDocXmlWriter);
            //TODO : move the plugin name from Plugins.xml to ProfileCatalog.xml

            profileCatalogDocXmlWriter.Close();
            pluginDocXmlWriter.Close();
        }
```

**NOTE** there is xmlns difference between both files.
when i move the node from Plugins.xml to ProfileCatalog.xml it adds the element as

```
<ModuleInfo AssemblyFile="PluginXXX.dll" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/pag/cab-profile" />
```

I want to remove this xmlns before adding to this file.

kindly give me a solution.

Comment: I solved this problem :)

Comment: It would be OK (encouraged even) for you to post your solution as an answer to your own question.

Comment: you can actually post the solution as an answer below then mark it as an answer to your own question. Otherwise it still looks like this question is open when you added the solution to the original question. A separate post is preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

while creating a new node to move in ProfileCatalog.xml

i replaced

```
 pRes.Add(pluginToMove);
```

with

```
pRes.Add(new XElement(pns+ "ModuleInfo", new XAttribute("AssemblyFile", pluginToMove.Attribute("AssemblyFile").Value)));
```